# If $g(n) \neq O(f(n))$, is $g(n) = \Omega(f(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics, examples-counterexamples

Given the positive functions $f(n), g(n)$, if $g(n)\neq O(f(n))$ then $g(n) = \Omega(f(n))$.

Is this correct?

I think not cause if $f$ does not set an upper limit to $g$ we can't be sure that the lower limit would be set by $f$. I mean that it can be lower than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct: it’s not necessarily true. For an easy example take $$f(n)=\begin{cases}
2^n,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
2^{-n}&\text{if }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$

and $$g(n)=\begin{cases}
2^n,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
2^{-n}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

This is not true even with the additional restriction that $f$ and $g$ are monotone increasing. Take $f(n) = (\text{largest even number } \leq n)! $, and $g(n) = (\text{largest odd number } \leq n)!$. Then
$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \begin{cases}
n, & \text{ if } n \text{ is even,} \\ \\
\frac{1}{n}, & \text{ otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$
which takes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values. Thus $f$ and $g$ cannot be compared using the $O$ or $\Omega$ relations.

*EDIT (Feb 1):* Simplified the counterexample.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last paragraph?

Comment: @Raphael: My notation is admittedly a little poor. Do you want a better explanation for the functions? Or do you want a proof that the pair of functions provides a counterexample?

Comment: The latter, if you'd be so kind. It is probably not hard, but not immediate (at least not to me). I have no problems with your notation (although the use of flooring brackets is arguably a bad idea).

Comment: @Raphael If $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are the two functions.  Evaluate $f(n) / g(n)$ at $n = (2k)!$ and $n = (2k+1)!$. This will show that $f(n)/g(n)$ takes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small positive values...

Comment: @Raphael: I simplified my counterexample a lot. Hopefully the new answer is better and easier to follow. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: That's much better, thanks! =)

Answer (score 3):

Simple example is $f(n) = n \cdot \cos(n), g(n) = n  \cdot \sin(n)$, there is no $O, \theta, \Omega$ relation between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Maybe the answer can be fixed, but as written, this is not a counterexample: $|g(n)| = n |\sin n| \leqslant n = O(f(n))$.

Comment: @Srivatsan is right that this does not work, but the idea that $g(n)$ could be abnormally small from time to time is a good one. Consider for example $f(n)=n\cos(n)$ and $g(n)=n\sin(n)$, then $f\notin O(g)$ and $g\notin O(f)$. This kind of construction has a simplicity I personally like. So, Saeed, your idea was a good one, which only needed to be pushed a little further...

Comment: @DidierPiau, thanks, I fixed my answer.