# Is it possible that $f(n) \not\in O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \not\in O(f(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

As the question stated, can I find any two functions $f(n)$  and $g(n)$ such that they satisfy:

1. $f(n) \not\in O(g(n))$
2. $g(n) \not\in O(f(n))$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104072/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\\
n & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$g(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
n & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$